# How to extract specific HTML tags in Android

Tags: android, html, regex

I want to extract some data from the following HTML code:

```html
<a href="url" id="" title="" target="" ></a>
<br/>
<a href="url" id="" target="_blank" onclick="" style="" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="">‪NASA: Dawn Performing ‘Flawlessly’ on Ceres‬</a><br/>www.discovery.com
<br/>‪Just over one month into its Ceres mission, NASA’s Dawn spacecraft is performing “flawlessly”, the agency said in a news release.‬
```

I want to get:

1. The text between last a tags if there are many a tags:

   ```
   NASA: Dawn Performing ‘Flawlessly’ on Ceres
   ```
2. The text after next `<br/>`:

   ```
   www.discovery.com
   ```
3. The text after next `<br/>`:

   ```
   Just over one month into its Ceres mission, NASA’s Dawn spacecraft is performing “flawlessly”, the agency said in a news release.‬
   ```

How can I do it using regular expression? Or is there better way?

Comment: Can the regex be for `sed` or any other shell program?

Comment: You should not parse HTML with regex, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I don't know, I think that post is a little bit extreme. The OP's demand is straightforward and easy to implement in regex. I cannot see what could possible go wrong grepping for information located in such logically determined places.

Comment: It can be done jsoup. It would be better if you a site link so that it would be easy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as `html/XML parsing`, the Android developer website [has a nice guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html).
Also, it does not have to be Android-specific, any Java parser will do.

Regex is bad practice for this.

Answer (score 0):

Html is just another Markup Language, so you need to parse it into your `POJO`.
You can use `JSoup Library` for parsing HTML easily. 
Here is a nice example of Parsing HTML from a Url and getting specific Data according to your needs. (Using JSoup Library)

```
class MyHTMLParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Elements> {
    Document doc;
    Elements words;
    String what1="failed";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        tvInfo.setText("Please wait...");
    }

    protected Elements doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        String url=params[0];
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            words = doc.select("b");
            what1 = words.text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return words;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Elements result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //tvInfo.setText(result);
        String menu = "";
        ArrayList<String> lunch = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> dinner = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListIterator<Element> postIt = result.listIterator();

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(postIt.hasNext()){
                lunch.add(postIt.next().text());
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(postIt.hasNext()){
                dinner.add(postIt.next().text());
            }
        }

        String[] lunch1 = new String[lunch.size()];
        lunch.toArray(lunch1);
        String[] dinner1 = new String[dinner.size()];
        dinner.toArray(dinner1);

        menu = "Lunch: \n" + lunch1[0] + "\n" + lunch1[1] + "\n" + lunch1[2] + "\n" + "\n" + "Dinner: \n" + dinner1[0] + "\n" + dinner1[1] + "\n" + dinner1[2] + "\n";
      Log.v("MyHTMLParser", "parsed menu = "+menu);
    }
}

//Somewhere in Your onCreate(...) Method
String URL="https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~ayiu/revmenu.html";
myHtmlParser = new MyHTMLParser();
myHtmlParser.execute(URL);
```

You can download `Jsoup Library` from this link: 
[Jsoup Library](http://jsoup.org/download)

I hope this helps.